# Persist java.net.URI Object as String in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I am persisting an instance of `java.net.URI` in a Mongo DB in a Spring Boot application.

For example, given the following Kotlin data class:

```
data class MyData(id: String, uri: URI)
```

I am persisting the object in a Mongo DB, and want it to be saved as a simple string, e.g., `path/to/file.txt`. However, when using this example string, my database has the following value:

```
{
   "id": "abcde1234",
   "uri": {
    "port": -1,
    "path": "path/to/file.txt",
    "schemeSpecificPart": "path/to/file.txt",
    "hash": 0,
    "string": "path/to/file.txt"
  }
}
```

I am persisting with the following (showing relevant parts only):

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface MyRepo: CrudRepository<Campaign, String>

@Service
class MyService(val myRepo: MyRepo) {
  fun create(myData: MyData) = myRepo.save(myData)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What code do you use to persist it?

Comment: @Enselic I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Spring Boot 2.2.0.M2 (which should be released [October 16](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestone/145)):

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.FieldType.STRING


data class MyData(
        val id: String,

        @Field(targetType = STRING)
        val uri: URI
)
```

The id field can also be forced to a specific datatype:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.FieldType.STRING
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoId
import java.util.UUID

data class MyData(
        @MongoId(targetType = STRING)
        val id: UUID,

        @Field(targetType = STRING)
        val uri: URI
)
```